# Run each loop on json sub-array

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have a json array with a subarray within it formatted like this:

```
[{"id":"188","stars":"2","staryes":"2","starers [{"starfirstname":"Name1","starlastname":"Name1","staruser":"1"},
{"starfirstname":"Name2","starlastname":"Name2 ","staruser":"3"}],"time":"1364151043","postedby":"43","text":"TEST","firstname":"Name3","lastname":"Name3","picture":"806243.jpg"}]
```

I can run a loop on the entire array by doing this:

```
 $.each(data, function(i, data) { //function })
```

but I can't figure out how to get a loop to run on the sub array 'starers'

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: Your json is invalid, fix it and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your JSON really is valid, it's a regular JavaScript array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < thing.starers.length; i++) {
    var starer = thing.starers[i];

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `.each` callback, `data` will be each object that happens to have a `starers` property. So just loop again from there (I renamed `data` to `item` for clarity):

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) { 
    $.each(item.starers, function(i, starer) { 
        // do something
        // e.g. alert(starer.starfirstname);
    });
});
```